# How do I get my "path" array list sorted the same way my "name" array list is getting sorted?

Tags: java, android

I've 2 array list having the same size named as "name" and "path" containing the name and path of the files respectively (which I got from reading external storage using a search function which I made).).

Now after, I've sorted the "name" array list according to alphabetical order case insensitive but the "path" array list remains the same.

I want to use these array lists in my list view, but the problem is when I click any file from listview and as we know that only one array list of "name" was sorted so they are not opening the correct file from its corresponding path because the "path" array list still contains the path of the old order of the "name" list.

So how can I make the "path" array list in the same order as the "name" list? In order to match new name list with their correct path.

If possible can someone help me through Teamviewer? I can't post the entire code here as this is my University project, I hope you all can understand.

Comment: why dont you make an arraylist of objects that has both the name and path as attributes to the object?

Comment: Right: keep things together that belong together.

Comment: As @ aquaballin rightly said ,Create a custom class and have two property name and path .now sort this arraylist based on name field .

Comment: I can't as I need to use these files separately, let me know if there is way.

Comment: You can also create a HashMap with name as Key and path as Value.

Comment: So there are Files that have a name and path... the Files should be representing by a single object that has two attributes... name and path. Without any source code this question makes it difficult to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use a TreeMap (its a type of a HashMap which sorts from a-z) instead of 2 Array Lists.
The code could look like this:

```
private Map<String, String> namePathMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
```

Now to add a Path with a name you do as following:

```
namePathMap.put("[name]", "[path]");
```

this will sort the HashMap by the keys.

If you want to get the path by the given mame, you have to write:

```
namePathMap.get("[name]");
```

If you now need to iterate over the names:

```
for(String key : namePathMap.keySet()){
  String value = namePathMap.get(key);
  //Do here what you want
}
```

If you have any Questions to Maps/HashMaps feel free to ask me ^^
I hope I could help you

Comment: I changed it now it should be fine with the memory

Answer (score 0):

In your example, a `name` is used to get a `path`.

This represents a `key` and `value` type of data where a `key` is used in order to obtain its corresponding `value`.

Thus, instead of having two separate data structures (your two `ArrayList`), I would advise you to use a `Map`, specifically a `TreeMap` if you want your names to be sorted. A `TreeMap` will automatically sort the keys according to its *natural ordering*.

---

**Usage**

To instantiate a `TreeMap`:

```
Map<String, String> nameMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

To add a `name` key and `path` value pair:

```
nameMap.put(name, path);
```

To get the `path` from the `name`:

```
nameMap.get(path);
```

For more documentation, take a look at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html